# Create 10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1 in for loop php

Tags: php

Create a script that displays `10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1`. there will be no hyphen(-) at starting and ending position in php for loop.
I have created this

```
<?php
    for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
    {
        if($i!=10)
        {
            echo "$i-";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "$i";
        }
    }
?>
```

outputs

`1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10`

but I want this result `10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1`

Comment: please show us your best attempt (in the original question, not as a comment)

Comment: `$i=10; $i>=1; $i--` also change the condition to this `if($i!=1)`

Comment: _for($i=10; $i>=1; $i--){ //your code }_

Comment: this is not working

Comment: what exactly is _not working_? The comment by @Accountant is correct, give it a try

Comment: this for($i=10; $i>=1; $i--){ //your code } –

Comment: It works great [https://3v4l.org/C0F2r](https://3v4l.org/C0F2r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php for($i=10; $i>=1; $i--){
      if($i!=1) {
          echo "$i-";
      } else {
          echo "$i";
      }
  }  
?>
```

Comment: Check if this works for you

Comment: OK working thank you

Answer (score 2):

One line, using [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to generate the values from 10 down to 1, and [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to put them all together with hyphens between them:

```
echo implode('-', range(10, 1));
```

Output:

```
10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MXYkY)

Comment: @KaleemBhatti here's a proper one line solution...